# Header não fica responsivo em 320PX usando FlexBox

Tags: html, css, flexbox, layout-responsivo

estou começando a utilizar flexbox porem estou com um problema gigante que não consigo resolver em diversos layouts. Tanto o header como o nav e li ficam escondidos na resoluçao Mobile,Iphone 320x568 e fica uma lista branca em todo site. Já tentei max width no @media e @media screen e nada.

Alguma sugestação? Por Favor <3

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
    <title>Infinity</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/logo.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.2.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-hWVjflwFxL6sNzntih27bfxkr27PmbbK/iSvJ+a4+0owXq79v+lsFkW54bOGbiDQ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>
        <header>
    <a href="#"><img src="images/logo2.png" alt="Infinity"></a>
    <nav>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </nav>
        </header>
</body>
</html>

CSS : /* RESET */
* {
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
}

nav,ul {
    list-style: none;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}


/* HEADER */
header {
    background-color: #353535;
    max-width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 1px 50px;
}

header img {
    width: 200px;
}

header nav {    
    display: flex;
}
header li a {
    color: white;
    padding: 30px;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
}
header li a:hover {
    color:#606060;
}
header li{
    margin: 0 15px;
}

header li:first-child {
    margin-left: 0;
}
header li:last-child {
    margin-right:0;
}

@media (max-width: 700px) {
    header {
        flex-direction: column;
    }
    header img {
        margin-bottom: 15px;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 320px){
    header a {
        flex-direction: column;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Seu CSS e HTML estão com uns probleminhas. A sua lista por exemplo não tem uma `UL` por fora, e os `margins` e `paddins` estão meio redundantes. Outra coisa é que a fonte não é "responsiva"por natureza, vc precisa fazer ajustes nela para se adequarem ao layout. Eu usei alguns `@media` para ajustar o `font-size` e corrigir isso

Fiz apenas alguns pequenos ajuste no que comentei e já resolveu, olha ai.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
}

nav,
ul {
  list-style: none;
}

ul {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  background-color: #353535;

}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* HEADER */

header {
  background-color: #353535;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 1px 50px;
}

header img {
  width: 200px;
}

header nav {
  display: flex;
}

header li a {
  color: white;
  /* padding: 30px; */
  font-size: 1.4rem;
}

header li a:hover {
  color: #606060;
}

header li {
  margin: 0 15px;
}

header li:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}

header li:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

@media (max-width: 700px) {
  header {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  header img {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
  }
  header li a {
    font-size: 1rem;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 360px) {
  header li a {
    font-size: 0.75rem;
  }
}
```

```html
  <header>
    <a href="#">
      <img src="images/logo2.png" alt="Infinity">
    </a>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">About</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Products</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado.Salvou demais. Voce é o cara!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @MatheeusLuiiz que bom que te ajudou, se a sua dúvida já foi respondida considere marcar a resposta como aceita, nesse ícone ✔ a lado da resposta, assim a pergunta não fica pendente no site como Pergunta sem Reposta Aceita. Boa sorte com o projeto. E qualquer dúvida é só dar o toque